# Why does myPhpAdmin open in a different browser to the one that is set as default?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, default-programs, opera, default-browser

I have 3 browsers installed on my Ubuntu 11.10, Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

First I had the problem that Software Center did not respect my default browser choice. I fixed that by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

But still when I open myPhpAdmin (a link that shows up in Unity dash) it insists on opening in Opera.

config outputs this (and why does Opera has 200 priority and 2 entries in this table?)

```
  Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/opera              200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/opera              200       manual mode
```

Comment: Also when I use Geany and go to menu press help it will open Opera browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe Software Center uses gnome-www-browser rather than x-www-browser. So you could try to use that procedure to set gnome-www-browser instead:

```
update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```